# Expandable listview repeating group data Android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom BaseExpandableListAdapter, Populating the ExpandableListView works fine.
This is my list that i'm passing has this structure structure:

```
    public Class GroupList{
            String id,name;
            List<ChildList> childList;
    }

    public class ChildList{
            String id,name;
    }
```

Now I create a list in my Activity of type GroupList and pass it to the custom adapter.
The problem that i'm having is, when two children, in the expandableListView are expanded, other children are being duplicated/repeated.

Been trying to debug this but failed. I will also put in the adapter class for reference:

```
    public class ADPTPresetsExpandableList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private List<GroupList> groupList;
    Button btElvPresets;
    public ADPTPresetsExpandableList(Activity pContext,List<GroupList> groupList) {
        if(pContext != null)this.activity = pContext;
        if (groupList != null)this.groupList = groupList;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupList.get(groupPos).getChildList().get(childPos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return childPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int grpPos, int childPos, boolean arg2, View childView,ViewGroup arg4) {


            if(getChild(grpPos, childPos)!=null){
                ChildList childNode = (ChildList)getChild(grpPos, childPos);

                childView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.expandablelistview_presets_child, null);

                TextView tvChildPresetTitle = (TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tvPresetChildTitle);
                tvChildPresetTitle.setText(childNode.getName());

            }



        return childView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupList.get(arg0).getChildList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int pos, boolean arg1, View groupView, ViewGroup arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (groupView == null){

            GroupList groupList =(GroupList) getGroup(pos);
            groupView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandablelistview_presets_group,null);
            TextView tvChildPresetTitle = (TextView)groupView.findViewById(R.id.tvPresetChildTitle);
            tvChildPresetTitle.setText(groupList.getName());

            }
        return groupView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you done any changes to onClick? I was thinking that in this case there might be a logical error there that is causing this problem. Otherwise I would advise you to start debugging on your device and step by step go through what happends. Put a break points on all your functions in the class ADPTPresetsExpandableList.

Comment: ya I debugged and found the mistake, which indeed was very stupid. But still not sure about why the problem was created, this null check was the issue:  if (groupView == null).. Thanks for the reply, appreciate it...

Comment: Well I think I got the whole problem understood. The get view method was returning the updated view only under the condition that groupView/childView was null.

Comment: Great. Submit the solution to your post so that you can later mark it as solved.